# Tensor sizes CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

In the snippet:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
raw_loss = criterion(output.view(-1, ntokens), targets)
```

*output* size is torch.Size([5, 5, 8967]), *targets* size is torch.Size([25]), and *ntokens* is 8967

After modifying the code, my

*output* size is torch.Size([5, 8967]) and *targets* size is torch.Size([25])

which rises dimensionality issues when computing the loss.

Is it sensible to increase the size of my Linear activation that produces the *output* by 5, so that I can resize the *output* later to be of the size torch.Size([5, 5, 8967])?

The problem with increasing the size of the tensor is that *ntokens* can become quite large and I can easily run out of memory because of that. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: have a ceiling for ntokens... eg only take most frequent 10000 tokens in to account, everything else replace by <unk> token.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
ntokens = 8000
output = Variable(torch.randn(5, 5, ntokens))
targets = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.randint(0, ntokens, size=25)))
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = criterion(output.view(-1, ntokens), targets)
print(loss)
```

This prints:

```
Variable containing:
 9.4613
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

Here, I am assuming `output` contains predictions of next word for 5 sentences (minibatch size is 5) and each sentence is of length 5 (sequence length is 5). 8000 is the vocabulary size, so your model is predicting a probability distribution over the entire vocabulary.
Now, you can compute the loss of predicting each word as your target shape is `25` as required.

Please note, [CrossEntropyLoss](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) expects input to contain scores for each class. So, input has to be a `2D` Tensor of size `(minibatch, C)` and the target has to be a class index (0 to C-1) for each value of a 1D tensor of size minibatch.

Comment: In your case output is 5x5xntokens, while targets are 25. In my case output is 5xntokens and targets 25

Comment: @MocialovBoris would you explain what your output actually is and what is target? Why output shape is 5xntokens and target is 25? Please briefly explain, so that we can help you.

Comment: the input is a sequence of words, for example, from position i:i+seq_length. The target will then be i+1:i+seq_length+1. I think the issue is that you assumed that the target is one word only and it was my fault that I have not specified that. Target is also flattened before feeding into the loss (aka .view(-1))

Comment: My output from the forward function is batch_sizexvocab_size By following your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086221/lstm-with-attention

Comment: Would you mind joining the chat room to make this more efficient https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167097/room-for-mocialov-boris-and-wasi-ahmad